Evils are in glass building/hotel and a kid enters it
First, I didn't see this movie. My sister told the story to me. But she forgets the movie's name. Here is the story:
In a village/town, there is a glass building/hotel. No one will even go into that building because devils/spirits/evils are living in it. If someone enters into that building, the rooms automatically change every 2 minutes. When they change, if any devil is in the same room with a person it will kill them. 
Hero's family come to that town to stay there. His kid plays with a ball and that ball accidentally goes into that hotel. SO this kid also goes into that building to bring back his ball. Now the hero's family also goes to that building to save their kid. They have some special equipment to see the evils and to kill them. Movie climax is that the boy safely comes out of the building, but his family has some injuries.
This is the story my sister told me. Any guess?

Any other meta information your sister provided? When did she watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from?

@NapoleonWilson. Sorry, She told me this story a year ago.

It doesn't fit too well in all aspects, but given that the question is only based on hearsay and memories can be a bit unreliable in the first place anyway, I'll try with Thir13en Ghosts:

Arthur and his two children, Kathy and Bobby, inherit his Uncle
  Cyrus's estate: a glass house that serves as a prison to 12 ghosts.
  When the family, accompanied by Bobby's Nanny and an attorney, enter
  the house they find themselves trapped inside an evil machine
  "designed by the devil and powered by the dead" to open the Eye of
  Hell. Aided by Dennis, a ghost hunter, and his rival Kalina, a ghost
  rights activist out to set the ghosts free, the group must do what
  they can to get out of the house alive.

It features a family in an interesting glass house full of ghosts that repeatedly changes to some degree and they also use special glasses to see the ghosts. Though other things don't match, like that nobody wants to go there and that the family only enters by accident.
Though, I think the aspect of the kid accidentally entering because of a ball/toy might be there on a smaller scale, where he accidentally enters not the house but the basement inside the house (which is also where the ghosts are initially kept). So that might just be a misrememberance on your sister's side.

Thought the same but look like a long shot to me.

@AnkitSharma Not so long when considering that the question is basically second hand information and most of the memorable stuff is actually there.

After whatching trailer, thir13en gohosts looks very familiar to my story. And my sister told me that they have glasses to see the ghosts. So there is a lot of chance to say, this is the correct movie
